# Load error using PHP variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to execute a JavaScript command when the page loads, using PHP variable.

I am getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: `Cannot read property 'style' of null(…)`

```
<head>
    //cut out some stuff here
    <script>
        function openTab(tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("panel_wrapper");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            console.log("fking debug "+tabName);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="openTab('<?php $_SESSION["loc"] ?>')">
    //cut out some stuff here too
<body>
```

I've echoed `$_SESSION["loc"]` and it is "settings", a correct tab name that does work. Replacing the variable with "settings" didn't work either.

I know that something has not been set or something, hence it's null. Could it be something to do with PHP loading before the script?

NOTE: I'm still new to PHP, and the tab script code is by W3Schools.

Comment: Either `tabcontent[i]` or `tab links[i]` is null, possibly. Find out which line it's coming from, and do some logging.

Comment: The element doesn't exist, so either you're passing the wrong ID, or it isn't there

Comment: What happens if you change `<?php $_SESSION["loc"] ?>` to `<?php echo $_SESSION["loc"] ?>`

Comment: @aynber Chrome is telling me the error is at line 20, which is `document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";`. My debug message only works when I am clicking on the different tabs, and not when I try to load (in this case).

Comment: Throw your logging line before line 20, so you can see exactly what is getting passed, so you can make sure that the value is correct.

Comment: @Howzieky Works with echo in front of it, thanks!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with this line:
`<body onload="openTab('<?php $_SESSION["loc"] ?>')">`
You are accessing `$_SESSION["loc"]`, but you aren't echoing it. change that line to:

`<body onload="openTab('<?php echo $_SESSION["loc"]; ?>')">`